# need to know python3 keyword for placeholder similar to python 2

Tags: python

```
name = 'marcog'
number = 42
print '%s %d' % (name, number)
```

above program is executed in Python 2 but not in Python 3.

`%s` and `%d` are place holders that can replace the values in python 2.  I need to know similar syntax in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to format strings in Python 3.

These should all work:

`print('{} {}'.format(name, number})`

`print('{name} {number}'.format(name=name, number=number))`

`print(f'{name} {number})'` (in Python >=3.6)

More info: https://pyformat.info/

EDIT: As everyone else is pointing out, the issue is with the `print` statement. These other, newer, formatting options are generally recommended though.

Comment: `%` formatting still works on Python 3. The questioner's error has nothing to do with `%` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

for python 3 the syntax would be:

```
print('%s %d' % (name, number))
```

In python 3 print is the function rather than the statement, placeholders (%s or %d) will work same.